# I need to occasionally restart my router to fix my internet connection. Can I detect it with a script and restart automatically?

Tags: internet, script, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I am using buffalo router WZR-HP-G300NH with DD-wrt firmware. The internet sometimes slows down and the devices cannot even join the WiFi. If I reboot the router, everything is back to normal. This happens several times a day. Is there any script to detect the the problem in the router and restart automatically?

Comment: If the internet slowdown is sufficient, you could certainly write a script that tests the speed periodically and reboots the router if it falls below a threshold. I would suggest first that you get some more information on why it is failing. Have you found any clues in the router's logs leading up to the events? If you haven't already, make sure you enable `syslogd` and use the command `cat /tmp/var/log/messages` to dump the log when it is running poorly. Also check `dmesg` as it may have kernel messages syslog doesn't. With this info you may be able to fix the issue instead of a work around.

Comment: See http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Index:Scripting for samples of dd-wrt scripts; there is an 'automatic connection' repair sample that will attempt a repair if a connection goes completely down that could be helpful.

Comment: why bother?  you will only get frustrated while its rebooting.  Get a new router.

Comment: @Keltari +1

But first i'd try re-flashing the router. I had similar issue with openwrt - it kept getting kernel panic and disabling network adapters. Newer version and reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

1. Enable JFFS support on Internal Flash Storage via Administration >
   Management page.
2. SSH to your router and save the following in `/jffs/checkConnection.sh`.

This is a trimmed down version of what I use which also sends me slack messages when the internet is restored. Basically, we're pinging a well-known URL. If it responds, the Internet is up, otherwise it's down. If the connection is deemed to be down, we store the current timestamp in a file (if we haven't already done this) and reboot. When the connection is back up, we read that file and log how long the connection was down for. The various log statements and echos are there so you get output whether you run the script manually, piped to a log file or via CRON.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/opt/usr/bin"

ping -c4 google.com > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
   if [ ! -f /jffs/rebooted ]; then
       echo `date '+%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'` > /jffs/rebooted
   fi
   message="Connection down, rebooting..."
   logger -s -t "custom.checkConnection" "$message"
   echo $message
   reboot
elif [ -f /jffs/rebooted ]; then
   ts=`cat /jffs/rebooted`
   message="Internet restored, was down since $ts"
   rm -rf /jffs/rebooted
   logger -t "custom.checkConnection" "$message"
   echo "$message"
else
   echo "Everything looks good!"
fi
```

You can run it manually or set a CRON task to run it every 5 minutes or so:

```
*/5 * * * * root /jffs/checkConnection.sh
```